# Formula for percentage

Tags: math

I have an *int* named Value with a random number.
I need to display in a label the percentage (0–100%), according to Value.

For example, if Value is 30 of 60, then the percentage should be 50%. What formula should I use?

Comment: "If value is 30, the percentage should be 50%".. Riight

Comment: If the value of int is 30 of 60, the percentage of the label should be 50% ... Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(random_value / max_value) * 100
```

Comment: This will fail in common programming languages when `random_value` and `max_value` have integer types, since an integer division will be performed. Either a type such as floating point should be used or the expression should be altered to produce the desired precision (e.g., `(100*random_value+max_value/2)/max_value`).

Answer (score -2):

something like this?

```
if($value > 30 && $value < 60) {
 $percentage = '50%';
} else {
 $percentage = ($value / $max_value) * 100 . '%';
}
```

Comment: This answer makes even less sense than the question.  In the first branch you calculate `$percentage` without having a ratio of two numbers; any `value` in `30<v<60` is `50%` of what ?

Comment: Now I have read it second time and yes, you are true :D I was reading it like 'if the value is between 30 and 60 the percentage should be 50 ' :D just woke up when was writing, excuses :] then the question is totally nonsense and the author should go to the school :]